# svn to git, create-ignores does not work

Tags: git, svn, gitignore, svnignore

I try to convert a subversion repo to git with "git svn ..."

(guide from http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git)

Unfortunately "git svn create-ignore" does not work:

```
config --get svn-remote.svn.fetch :refs/remotes/git-svn$: command returned error: 1
```

How can I get the svn:ignore properties to .gitignore files?

Comment: The guide does not mention `create-ignore`, just `show-ignore`.

Comment: The show-ignore command does not work too. It shows all svn:ignore entries.

Comment: "It shows all svn:ignore entries." But this is the purpose of `show-ignore`?

Comment: I think I ran into a similar issue with `show-ignore`. You might want to try the solution I found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25254694/1394393.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question.

I wrote a little script. You need the old SVN directory and the new git directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, subprocess

svn_dir=sys.argv[1].rstrip('/') # usage: python ... svn_dir git_dir
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(svn_dir, '.svn')):
    print 'Not a svn-dir:', svn_dir
    sys.exit(1)

git_dir=sys.argv[2].rstrip('/')
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(git_dir, '.git')):
    print 'Not a git-dir:', git_dir
    sys.exit(1)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(svn_dir):
    dirs[:]=[d for d in sorted(dirs) if not d in ['.svn']]
    pipe=subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'propget', 'svn:ignore', root],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    git_ignore_lines=[]
    for line in pipe.stdout.readlines():
        line=line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        git_ignore_lines.append(line)
    if not git_ignore_lines:
        continue
    git_ignore_dir=os.path.join(git_dir, root[len(svn_dir)+1:])
    if not os.path.exists(git_ignore_dir):
        os.makedirs(git_ignore_dir)
    git_ignore=os.path.join(git_ignore_dir, '.gitignore')
    if os.path.exists(git_ignore):
        old=open(git_ignore).read().split()
    else:
        old=[]
    old.extend(git_ignore_lines)
    fd=open(git_ignore, 'wt')
    seen=set()
    for line in old:
        if line in seen:
            continue
        fd.write('%s\n' % line)
        seen.add(line)
    fd.close()
    print 'wrote', git_ignore
```

Comment: Can you explain what the original problem was, and how this script solves it?

Comment: @Ovesh from my question: `git svn create-ignore` failed.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean, what was the _underlying_ problem, and how does your solution relate to it?

Or did you just decide to work around it?

Comment: @Ovesh The underlying problem is, that we were unhappy with svn and want to use git. I wanted to convert our svn repos to git. And I wanted to convert the ignore files of svn (svn tag svn:ignore) to git. And during this, the error if this question happens. Why do you want to know this?

Comment: I meant why was this error message displayed. Normally running `git svn create-ignore` finishes without any issues. Why was the error occurring? And how is it related to your fix?

Comment: @Ovesh I can't reproduce this any more. We have converted all svn repos to git. Why to you want to know?

Comment: I had this issue. I eventually worked around it, but I wanted to know if you understood what was causing the problem. If you wrote a script to fix it, I assumed you understood the problem as well.